# async and await supported ES version?

Tags: javascript

I am not able to find from which version ES is supported to async and await functions.
If anyone knows please attach link might add advantage.

```
async function asynchronus(){

}
```

Comment: ES 2017.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await

Comment: thanks @JaromandaX

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find it on the [MDN-Async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) and [MDN-Await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await).

Async and Await are standard sinds ECMAScript 2017.
Await has some issues in the ECMAScript 2017 version.
It will be fixed in ECMAScript 2018